# Hibernate mapping different Table to one POJO class

Tags: hibernate, db2, hibernate-mapping

Hibernate mapping different Table to one POJO class

I have requirement to map two different tables to one POJO class in hibernate.

I have tried configuring hibernate mapping using join but I get error like

`DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704.`

My table relation is shown in the figure.

[image]

My hibernate mapping is below.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mydomain.Student" table="STUDENT_TABLE" schema="UNIV">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="studentId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="STUDENT_ID" />
        </property>

        <property name="course" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="COURSE_ID" />
        </property>

        <join table="COURSE_TABLE"  >  
            <key column="COURSE_ID" />    
                <property name="courseName" type="string">
                  <column name="COURSE_NAM" />
                        </property>  

                        <property name="courseTeacher" type="string">
                    <column name="COURSE_Teacher" />
                         </property>            

        </join>

   </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

My student class has getter and setter for.

```
id
studentId
    course
courseName
courseTeacher
```

Can somebody help me to fix this mapping issue?

Comment: Your requirement is somewhat unexpected.. Your mapping seems to go disarray. looking at your student class it seems studentId is foreign-key... which will have details of students, and id will be primary-key for rest fields.. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your table relation diagram. Your database designing is wrong.

> One student can enroll for more than 1 course. And 1 course can
>   contain more than 1 students.

So basically its a **many-many** mapping.

Here are some examples for you to achieve it.

[Example1](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-xml-mapping-example/)

[Example2](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/)

**UPDATE**

I was improvising your design the correct way. But if you still insist that its 0ne-one mapping, then here is a [similar question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141972/hibernate-mapping-two-tables-in-one-hbm-file-with-same-class-name). You will require id's to be exact so that it corresponds to one record only. Have look at [hibernate-doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-join) for the same.

Comment: i have just give this as example. My table relation is simply one to one.

Comment: Basically i want to join using column which is not a primary in student table.

Comment: My question is how to map multiple table to single pojo. i.e when i select student i would like to get course name and course teacher also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified the names of all your columns are correct in the hibernate mapping? Looking up the [error code -204](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/db2z_sqlcodes.htm), it says "name IS AN UNDEFINED NAME."